# Is it possible to rake db:seed just one model? - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering - is it possible to `rake db:seed` a model rather than the whole models in the app?

For example, if I have a seed data for `events`, `users`, `restaurants` - and i wanted to `rake db:seed` only `events`, rather than typing `rake db:seed` in the terminal, is there a command that allows you to `rake db:seed` only `events` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use your custom rake task to build what you want. The task rake db:seed is just a helper to get you organised from the beginning. But you can also add under YOUR_APP/lib/tasks your custom rake tasks.

http://cobwwweb.com/how-to-write-a-custom-rake-task

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem called Seedbank (https://github.com/james2m/seedbank) which would suit your purposes well. It allows you to split your seeds into different files, and then run a rake task on them individually.